# Can login via facebook, but cannot login via my email

Tags: support, user-accounts

In stackoverflow.com, I have two logins:

1. email as athos.liu@gmail.com,
2. OpenID via facebook.

I started with 1) but later found 2) is quite convenient.

After login via facebook, click "logins":

[image]

Now, my office network blocked facebook, so I have to login Stack Overflow using the 1st account.

However I can't login using "athos.liu@gmail.com" anymore! It says "No account with this email found"!

[image]

How could I link my 2 accounts together, so that I can login via my email account in office?

Answer (score 2):

Just go here: https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register

...And create a SE OpenID account using that same email. It'll automatically let you into your account then.

Alternately, click the big "Log in with Google" button - since this is a Gmail email, it'll be automatically associated with your Google account (assuming you log in with that same email).

#### Background

That both Facebook and the email are shown as your logins reflects the nature of SE's login system: when you log in with a "trusted" provider (Google, Yahoo!, Facebook, SE OpenID), the email associated with *that* account is automatically associated with your SE account as well - thus allowing you to log in with *any other* trusted provider that returns the same email.